# select all the values of the records belonging to a specific field of the database and save them in a array Active Record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following set of records . I want to save in a array called @texts only
the values of the field text doing an each o a for

```
  1.9.3-p547 :074 > Tweet.all
  Tweet Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "tweets".* FROM "tweets" 
 => [#<Tweet id: 1, text: "hola a todos", zombie_id: 5, created_at: "2014-12-29 23:52:40", updated_at: "2014-12-29 23:52:40">, #<Tweet id: 2, text: "hola como estas", zombie_id: 5, created_at: "2014-12-30 00:09:40", updated_at: "2014-12-30 00:09:40">, #<Tweet id: 3, text: "hello", zombie_id: 5, created_at: "2014-12-30 12:44:41", updated_at: "2014-12-30 12:44:41">] 
1.9.3-p547 :075 > 

Example

@texts=["hola a todos","hola cmo estas", "hello"];
```

Comment: Please revise your question to be better understood.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this:

```
@texts = Tweet.all.map(&:text)
```

Or:

```
@texts = Tweet.pluck(:text)
```

Comment: [second variant is preferable](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Calculations/pluck)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [pluck](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck), as for the documentation:

> Use pluck as a shortcut to select one or more attributes without
>   loading a bunch of records just to grab the attributes you want.

This way you are only select the desired columns and not the "full" record.